# Xcode compile error - linker undefined symbol

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, linker-errors, apple-silicon

I need your help. My Xcode stopped compiling my code with errors as in the image.
My setup: Xcode 13.1, Cocoapods + DevPods

Code compiled until yesterday morning, and now does not compile. Whats weird is that even code I have pushed on Monday to AppStore throws exact same errors as on image.

Tried clearing caches, deintegrate pods and install them again, removed xcode and installed one more time with xcode-install. Even upgraded from Big Sur to Monterey today and this also changed nothing.

Same is for build for simulator and for device

Apple Silicon on board, Xcode and Cocoapods native (not Rosetta)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of my Dev pods decided for unknown reason to not link `libc++` ... I fixed this by adding to it's `.podspec` file this line:

```
s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-lc++' }
```